# Antlr: transform matched input on right side of a rule

Tags: tree, antlr

I'm trying to write a language parser and build a nice AST. In the language, a function is essentially a variable with a callable value. For example:

```
int f(int arg) {...};
#int(int) f: int(int arg) {...};
```

both are equal, and I want to transform the first into the second. As you can see, the variable's type contains parameters, but without name. The function value needs the parameter name.

So the question is: Is it possible to get both `(int arg)` and `(int)` back from my rule that matches a parameter list, or is it alternatively possible to transform the first into the second on the right of the `->`?

I'll add an example source and result tree below

```
Input:
^(FUN_DEF
  ^(TYPE_SIMP 'int')
  'f'
  ^(PARAM_LIST
    ^(PARAM 'int' 'arg')
   )
  ^(BLOCK ...)
 )

Result:
^(VAR_DEF
  ^(TYPE_FUN
    ^(TYPE_SIMP 'int')
    ^(PARAM_LIST
      ^(PARAM 'int')
     )
   )
  'f'
  ^(FUN
    ^(TYPE_SIMP 'int')
    ^(PARAM_LIST
      ^(PARAM 'int' 'arg')
     )
    ^(BLOCK ...)
   )
 )
```

Comment: So, `short f(byte a, int b) {...};` and `#short(byte, int) f: short(byte a, int b) {...};` are also the same? And `TYPE_SIMP` is the return type (`'short'`, in this case)?

Comment: Exactly. The `TYPE_FUN` is the function's signature without name. I'm not sure why I use `^(PARAM 'int')` instead of `^(PARAM ^(TYPE_SIMP 'int')), but I guess if there's a solution, both variants should be very similar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility would be invoke a custom method in your `shortFunction` rule that, given a `paramList`, would strip all identifiers from them leaving only the types and insert that tree in the proper place:

```
shortFunction
  :  type ID '(' paramList ')' block 
     -> ^( ... {customMethod($paramList.tree)} ... )
  ;
```

A demo:

### file: Fun.g

```java
grammar Fun;

options { 
  output=AST;
  ASTLabelType=CommonTree;
}

tokens {
  ROOT;
  PARAM;
  PARAM_LIST;
  BLOCK;
  VAR_DEF;
  FUN;
  TYPE_FUN;
  TYPE_SIMP;
}

@parser::members {
  private CommonTree stripIDs(CommonTree tree) {
    CommonTree copy = new CommonTree(new CommonToken(PARAM_LIST, "PARAM_LIST"));
    for(int i = 0; i < tree.getChildCount(); i++) {
      CommonTree temp = (CommonTree)tree.getChild(i);
      CommonTree child = new CommonTree(temp);
      child.addChild(new CommonTree((CommonTree)temp.getChild(0)));
      copy.addChild(child);
    }
    return copy;
  }
}

parse
  :  function+ EOF -> ^(ROOT function+)
  ;

function
  :  shortFunction
  |  longFunction
  ;

shortFunction
  :  type ID '(' paramList ')' block
     -> ^(VAR_DEF ^(TYPE_FUN ^(TYPE_SIMP type) {stripIDs($paramList.tree)}) ID ^(FUN ^(TYPE_SIMP type) paramList block))
  ;

longFunction
  :  '#' t1=type '(' typeList ')' ID ':' t2=type '(' paramList ')' block
     -> ^(VAR_DEF ^(TYPE_FUN ^(TYPE_SIMP $t1) typeList) ID ^(FUN ^(TYPE_SIMP $t2) paramList block))
  ;

paramList
  :  (param (',' param)*)? -> ^(PARAM_LIST param*)
  ;

param
  :  type ID -> ^(PARAM type ID)
  ;

typeList
  :  (type (',' type)*)? -> ^(PARAM_LIST ^(PARAM type)*)
  ;

type
  :  INT
  |  SHORT
  |  BYTE
  ;

block
  :  '{' '...' '}' -> ^(BLOCK '...')
  ;

SHORT : 'short';
BYTE  : 'byte';
INT   : 'int';
ID    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9')*;
SPACE : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;};
```

### file: Main.java

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String source = "#short(byte, int) f: short(byte a, int b) { ... } short f(byte a, int b) { ... }";
    FunLexer lexer = new FunLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(source));
    FunParser parser = new FunParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.parse().getTree();
    DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
    StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
    System.out.println(st);
  }
}
```

If you run the main class, you will see that the input:

```
#short(byte, int) f: short(byte a, int b) { ... } 
short f(byte a, int b) { ... }
```

produces two identical trees:

[image]

Comment: hmm... your shortFunction seems to assume that here is only one function argument and the type is equal to the return type: `^(PARAM_LIST type)`

imagine there is `int f(short arg)` or `int f(int arg1, int arg2)`, the `TYPE_FUN` would have only one param. so - how do I get the `(int, int)` out of the `(int arg1, int arg2)` from my fun?

sorry for the late feedback, it seems I have failed to activate the notification properly :S

Comment: @Silly Freak, see my revised answer.

Comment: Thank you! That was what I was searching for. I hoped for a non-java, antlr-only way, but I guess that is very good. Thank you especially for the tips that `{java();}` is possible in the right hand side and the example how to transform the tree properly using java!

Comment: @Silly Freak, you're welcome. However, note that it's `{java()}` and _not_ `{java();}` in this case.